# Are there any superheroes with the power of giving others super powers?

Tags: super-hero, powers

I know of many examples of super powers that can nullify other powers or even steal them, but I can't think of any that give powers to others.  Are there any superheroes whose **main** power is giving super powers to others?

- The granted powers must be a permanent thing, so once you've been granted a power, you just have it from that point on (unlike Rogue)
- Powers must be given to someone that is not the hero in question (unlike Rogue or Kirby)
- Granted powers are not simply an "awakening" or a sort of knowledge gain (like learning magic or "going super saiyan")
- Process is not just a transferring the power from someone/thing else (i.e. Green Lantern ring)

I'm not looking for any sort of list, just an example of this kind of power.  I've been thinking through DC and Marvel heroes, but none are coming to mind.

Comment: You're going to need to limit this to a particular publisher, line of comics, media, etc. Otherwise, one could list all of the Greek Gods who bestowed power, Yahweh, Merlin, The Prof from the Reckoners trilogy, etc.

Comment: Zordon, any Lion Turtle, Shazam, The Guardians (Green Lantern), etc...

Comment: Come on guys, you haven't given him a chance to respond to the criticism.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots an even better example from the Reckoner's would be Larcener.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm not looking at a specific list, but rather just a general yes/no answer with a single example.  If there are really so many that I had to pick a publisher, I'd prefer an example from DC or Marvel.

Comment: Galactus gave Silver Surfer the power cosmic...

Comment: Not a super hero, but there is a short story in N. K. Jemisin's [Hundred Thousand Kingdoms setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inheritance_Trilogy_(N.K._Jemisin)) that has a new, young god whose power is to raise humans to godhood.

Comment: If you expand your range of potential sources a bit, [Typhoid Croyd](http://wildcards.wikia.com/wiki/Sleeper) fits the bill.. somewhat.. He dispensed a new (mutated) Wild Card infection on people.. it [COULD](http://wildcards.wikia.com/wiki/Snotman) be a super power (Snotman became the Reflector, and Edward St. John Latham went from regular human to [Ace](http://wildcards.wikia.com/wiki/Loophole) ).  [or not](http://wildcards.wikia.com/wiki/Roulette).  Arguably, Loophole himself also qualifies.

Comment: I'm assuming that Tony Stark (who created not just Iron Man's armor, but the original version of the Guardsman armor, Jim Rhodes' War Machine armor, and Pepper Potts' Rescue armor. It tends to eventual fail the permanency test (because the armors can break down), and the "transferring power from someone/thing else". However, it was my first thought. Expanding slightly, *WHAT IF?* (1970s) #3 had Tony build armor for Giant-Man, Wasp, and others (Rick Jones, I think).

Comment: @RDFozz I had thought of heroes like Ironman and Batman, who made tools for others to use, but that's not their main power and it's not really the "my power is to give others powers" type of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Ack. My intent was to say I was assuming Tony Stark wouldn't qualify, for the reasons I stated above.

Comment: @DavidStarkey: Is there anything more I can add to my answer to improve it for you?

Comment: Not quite the same, but a character from [*Strong Female Protagonist*](http://strongfemaleprotagonist.com/) has as their only power the ability to amplify the superpowers of others. (which character is a spoiler.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I still feel this question is too broad, a Marvel example is [Leon Nunez](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Leon_Nunez_(Earth-616)), whose power is to give people tattoos that give them powers. This is his only superpower.

> Leon can grant superhuman powers to others through drawing iconic symbols. This is usually done through tattooing images onto others. These tattoos then give whatever power Leon believes them to bestow. However, each tattoo drains a little bit of Leon's will as each tattoo and corresponding power is an extension of his will. The upper limits of Leon's powers are not defined. He was able to give multiple powers to nearly one hundred individuals, and empower a reasonable facsimile or approximation of the Phoenix Force before falling into a coma.

Comment: For a longer list, consult examples at http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Bestowal

Comment: This is closer since it is his main power, but it still seems like it's the tattoo that is giving the power.

Comment: He gives him the tattoo that gives them the power. The tattoo would not give them the power if he did not give it to them. :) Or are you looking for something where the donor has to consciously sustain the power in others?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the character, but from the link you gave it's pretty close.  Assuming the same tattoo drawn by someone else didn't give powers (like a magic rune kinda thing), I'd say this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Indeed. As far as I can tell, they don't elaborate on how exactly it works, but the magic, so to speak, is in him, not the drawing, although he seems to require the drawing, perhaps as a way of focusing and/or anchoring the power.

Answer (score 5):

[Hawk Moth](http://miraculousladybug.wikia.com/wiki/Gabriel_Agreste), the main villain of Miraculous has this power. He uses his ‘evilized’ butterflies(akumas) to give power to people who possess strong negative emotions.

Comment: Question was asking heroes (not villains), but interesting nonetheless!

Comment: @Jenayah: To be fair, the source of Hawk Moth's powers are granted by a paired device+organism. Historically, heroic characters wielded this power (this is touched on *extremely* briefly in an episode), but it was lost for a long time... until it was found by what appears to be a very wealthy individual who craves more power. Anyway, good answer. When I saw this question pop up into the active questions, I immediately planned on adding this answer if it didn't already exist.

Answer (score 4):

Felix from [Super Sales on SuperHeroes](https://www.audible.com/pd/Sci-Fi-Fantasy/Super-Sales-on-Super-Heroes-Audiobook/B073BJD2F5) has the ability to "fix" things he owns.  Later he finds that he can also upgrade them, including people so long as he owns them (slavery is legal in this setting).  This includes adding super powers to them.

Answer (score 3):

[Othala](http://worm.wikia.com/wiki/Othala) from *Worm* has this power.

To quote the wikia:

> Othala had the ability to grant any one of several temporary
>   superpowers to people she touches. However, she cannot grant any of
>   these powers to herself, and she could only grant one power at a time.
>
> Among the powers she is known to be able to grant are pyrokinesis,
>   invincibility, regeneration, flight, super-speed, and augmented
>   strength. The invincibility she granted allowed the target to stand
>   unmoved in the face of a punch from Leviathan [which *really* says something].
>   The regeneration required conscious effort from the user to activate,
>   and it was slower on some body parts than others.
>
> Othala's power was limited to one person at a time. The duration it
>   lasted after she let go depended on the power, ranging from ~30
>   seconds to 2 minutes, with powers that "bend reality more" tending to
>   "burn out" faster, in terms of duration.

[Teacher](http://worm.wikia.com/wiki/Teacher), from the same series, can bestow [Thinker-type](http://worm.wikia.com/wiki/Thinker) (enhanced intelligence, perception, or other information-gathering abilities) and [Tinker-type](http://worm.wikia.com/wiki/Tinker) (tech-creation) powers to others at the cost of the recipient's other faculties and free will.

Comment: This is a good example, except the question is asking for a superhero who can give others permanent superpowers.

Comment: @Bellatrix Oh. I have no idea how I did not notice that. Still, maybe Teacher counts? His powers can last indefinitely, but only if he doesn't take them away; which he rarely does, because he gets free slaves/minions. (We don't know--yet--what would happen if he were to die.)

Answer (score 0):

In the TV series [Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_(TV_series)), Hiro's sidekick, [Ando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ando_Masahashi), developps a superpower of his own near the end of the third season. However, his power is useless alone, because he essentially is a battery for other's powers: *"At the end of the third volume, "Villains," he acquires the ability to massively amplify the power of any posthuman he touches"*.

Later, in the fourth volume, "Fugitives," Ando has learned to channel this energy into concussive blasts, projecting the energy outward to knock back any targets.